# command to cut a whole row from excel and past it to another sheet

Tags: excel, vbscript, copy-paste

is there any command to cut a whole row from excel and past it to another sheet using VB scripting

am using a excel sheet which has data in my work i need some particular rows totally to be cut and paste to another excel sheet

now am able to copy that particular rows to another sheet but is there any command or any thing to cut and paste to another sheet using VB scripting?

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what your askin for

```
Sub PasteRowDelete()
' Macro recorded 10/29/2001 by Thomas Urtis
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Illinois").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Cut
Sheets("Deleted Prospects").Select
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Illinois").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveCell.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Not sure,just trying to help